# when using pygithub, has occurred socket.gaierror

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, pygithub

i try to use pygithub module, an error occurred in tutorial code.

an error occurs that 'socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known', i don't know why.

this is my tutorial code:

```
user = Github("id", "password")

publicRepos = user.get_repos()

for repo in publicRepos:
    print repo.name
```

and i get the following error:

```
          .
          .
          .
          .

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
  self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
  for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not know
```

please tell me how to solve.

Comment: The host passed to getaddrinfo is incorrect or not reachable. Can you reach https://api.github.com/ by a browser?

Comment: Error is ocurred, after printing 100~400 repo.name.
The number of printing repo name is irregular.

Comment: Maybe you've reached the rate limit. See https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/